# EWS SaveHttpResponseHeaders Exception - An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am getting this error at the time of attachment.load

> **Error Message:**  An item with the same key has already been added..
> **Error Stack trace:** at
> System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentException(ExceptionResource resource)
> at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Insert(TKey key, TValue value, Boolean add) at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.Add(TKey key, TValue value) at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase.SaveHttpResponseHeaders(WebHeaderCollection
> headers) at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.ExchangeServiceBase.ProcessHttpResponseHeaders(TraceFlags
> traceType, IEwsHttpWebResponse response) at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.SimpleServiceRequestBase.ReadResponse(IEwsHttpWebResponse
> response) at
> Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.MultiResponseServiceRequest`1.Execute()
> at Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data.FileAttachment.Load(Stream
> stream) at
> ERSupportGetOutlookEmail.EmailExchange.SaveEmailContentToDB(EmailMessage
> email)

can anyone help..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an existing bug see https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/issues/45 and if your using this in a Multi threaded app https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-managed-api/pull/104 (ExchangeService isn't thread safe so shouldn't be used this way). If your using the nuget package for EWS it quite old and doesn't include all the latest fixes so I would suggest you pull the repo from GitHub and compile your own.

Comment: Thank you so much Glen Scales for your time and yes i am using EWS from nuget thats why i am confused, i thought it was an updated version.

Comment: No last update for that was 2015 which has a number of bugs that have been since fixed in the repo

Comment: I cloned that repo and build a local nuget package that I use that has these fixes. But still I have some issues. I'm running in docker (linux) and get this error for some tenant/mailbox/appointment. When I run it in debug from my machine (Windows) from VS2022 it works fine, no Exception.
I'm thinking this might be a difference between windows/linux but what.... It's hard to debug in this way